# Slow java printing - DocPrintJob

Tags: java, printing

I developed a Java desktop program that uses a thermal printer with the following code:

```
/**
 * printableObject extends Printable
 */
public static boolean print(Object printableObject, String printer_name) throws InterruptedException {
    InputStream printerTest = new ByteArrayInputStream("".getBytes());
    DocFlavor flavor = DocFlavor.INPUT_STREAM.AUTOSENSE;
    Doc myDoc = new SimpleDoc(printableObject, DocFlavor.SERVICE_FORMATTED.PRINTABLE, null);
    Doc docTest = new SimpleDoc(printerTest, flavor, null);
    HashPrintServiceAttributeSet aset = new HashPrintServiceAttributeSet();
    PrintRequestAttributeSet rset = new HashPrintRequestAttributeSet();
    PrintService[] services = PrintServiceLookup.lookupPrintServices(null, null);
    PrinterName printer = new PrinterName(printer_name, null);
    rset.add(OrientationRequested.PORTRAIT);
    rset.add(MediaSizeName.INVOICE);
    aset.add(printer);
    services = PrintServiceLookup.lookupPrintServices(null, aset);
    if (!priterIsReady(services[0], 5)) {
        return false;
    }

    if (services != null) {
        try {
            DocPrintJob docPrintJobTest = services[0].createPrintJob();
            docPrintJobTest.print(docTest, rset);
            if (!priterIsReady(services[0], 5)) {
                return false;
            }

            DocPrintJob job = services[0].createPrintJob();
            job.print(myDoc, rset);
            Thread.sleep(300);
            if (priterIsReady(services[0], 5)) {
                DocPrintJob job2 = services[0].createPrintJob();
                job2.print(docTest, rset);
                return priterIsReady(services[0], 5);
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        } catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } catch (PrintException pe) {
            pe.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return false;
}

public static boolean priterIsReady(PrintService printer, int max) throws InterruptedException {
    int count = 0;
    while (count < max) {
        AttributeSet att = printer.getAttributes();
        for (Attribute a : att.toArray()) {
            String attributeName;
            String attributeValue;
            attributeName = a.getName();
            attributeValue = att.get(a.getClass()).toString();
            if (attributeName.equals("queued-job-count")) {
                if (Integer.valueOf(attributeValue) == 0) {
                    return true;
                } else {
                    System.err.println(">>> queued-job-count: " + Integer.valueOf(attributeValue));
                }
            }
        }
        Thread.sleep(600 + 600 / 5 * count);
        count = count + 1;
    }
    return false;
}
```

The code works perfectly in my IDE or using the jar (java 1.8.0_73). The printing is fast. But using another notebook with similar configuration (i7, 8GB, Windows10) I have problem: the printing takes more than 10 seconds to start. The same JAR and the same printer, but java 1.8.0_101. In this period the document is in the print queue.
I used another notebook (i5, 8GB, Windows10) and I had the same delay.

I changed the above code and I tried to print without check if the printer is ready or print test, but the problem persists.

Has someone gone through this problem?
Is there another way that I can print a Printable Object?

Comment: *In this period the document is in the print queue* Not a Java problem then. Check your printer driver.

Comment: It is my prime suspect. But it's the same 64 bits driver for Windows 10. Another suspect would be the Java version. I'll look for another way to print, I don't find a solution. But I do not think it would change anything.